# Python regex parsing and putting into a multidimensional list

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I know that regex is the way to go here but I am woeful at writing regex expressions. I have a file where each line looks like this: "defenders\t2\n" and I want to remove the \t and the \n and put the word "defenders" into the [0] of my multidimensional list and put the number "2" in the [1] of my list. Is there an easy regex way to do this in python?

import re

```
d = []
with open("somefile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       word = re.search()
       rank = re.search()
       d.append([word][rank])
```

This is what I am trying but I do not know how to make it work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str.split`:

```
>>> "defenders\t2\n".split()
['defenders', '2']
```

To get a list using regex, you need to use `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\S+', "defenders\t2\n")
['defenders', '2']
```

Comment: And if he wants `line[1]` to be an int instead of a string, just do `line[1] = int(line[1])`